# Unable to connect to mongoDB running in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

Following this example: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/mongodb/

When trying to connect to mongoDB with: `mongo ip:27017`
(where ip is the name from boot2docker ip) + the port number from docker ps:

27017/tcp
or with -P
0.0.0.0:49155->27017/tcp

Either way I get the following errors:

> warning: Failed to connect to ip:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection
>   refused
>
> Error: couldn't connect to server ip:27017 (ip), connection attempt
>   failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148 exception: connect failed

Comment: use `docker logs <container>` and `ps` to check that mongodb is actually running and listening on the port you exposed.

Comment: ok checking the tutorial more in-depth: can you post the line from `docker ps` for the container? I think you confused the internal port with the public port.

Comment: Thanks you made me think again :-)

Comment: I hade the same and docker ps return:  mongo_1   /entrypoint.sh --smallfile ...   Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: Moved away to use a graph db(dgraph)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was using port `27017` instead of `49155` (doh, port forwarding)

```
0.0.0.0:49155->27017/tcp
```

Thanks to the ZeissS.

Comment: Those (like me) who got confused with the answer. use the following to connect. **$mongo IP:49155**

Comment: <pre>
If you are on a Mac and using Docker Machine, do the following:

1. Get the name of the VM running docker daemon
$ **docker-machine ls**

2. Get the VM's IP info
$ **docker-machine env <your VM name>**

3. Connect with the mongo client to the VM IP and the mongo mapped port
$ **mongo VM-IP:port**
</pre>

Comment: @Jardalu I'm still confused

Comment: @Aleksandrus replace "IP" with the ip address of your docker machine. See VMTrooper's reply.

Answer (score 25):

If you specified the correct port and still not able to connect to mongodb running in docker (like me), make sure you are using the service name (or container name) in your connection URL, e.g. `mongodb://mongodb_service:27017/mydb`, which is defined in your `docker-compose.yml` :

```
services:
  mongodb_service:
    image: mongo
```

I was using the `hostname` value and that's not the correct thing to do. You could verify this by looking at `docker inspect mongodb_service` in the `Aliases` section.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Is there a stable version of the mongo docker image perhaps?  Buggy buggy buggy stuff here.

Answer (score 12):

If you are on a Mac and using Docker Machine, do the following:

```
1. Get the name of the VM running docker daemon
$ docker-machine ls

2. Get the VM's IP info
$ docker-machine env 

3. Connect with the mongo client to the VM IP and the mongo mapped port
$ mongo VM-IP:port
```

Comment: This is a valid answer if you are using the VirtualBox/docker-machine (Windows/Mac) version of Docker.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your mongodb is within a container, for other containers to connect to it, they all need to be on the same network.

To have mongodb and other containers (that want to connect it), create a new network using below command

```
docker network create --driver bridge my_bridge
```

Then run mongodb and other containers using the --net flag

```
docker run --net=my_bridge --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 mongodb
docker run --net=my_bridge --name my-service -p 7002:7002 my-service
```

Now you should be able to connect mongodb with given alias name from those containers

```
mongo --host "mongodb:27017"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/db_name
```

Should be the Database URI for a service definition like below (and **not** `mongodb://localhost`
or `mongodb://IP`). Use service name or container name.

```
services  
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - '27017:27017'
```

Comment: specifying just the ports and not the container_name worked for me