# How to connect to MongoDB running in Docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, connection

I'm running a Docker container on MacOS that starts a Postgres server and MongoDB server as follows:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 27017:27017 dockertest
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
  ...done.
 * Starting database mongodb
  ...done.
```

The output shows that the MongoDB server is started correctly. Then I lookup the IP of the VM in which the container is running, like this:

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.2
```

The ports seem to be mapped:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
39e5198e4693        dockertest   "/bin/sh -c 'service "   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   drunk_nobel
```

However, when I want to connect to the MongoDB in another terminal window, using

```
mongo 192.168.99.100:27017
```

I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: 192.168.99.100:27017/test
2016-06-05T18:48:19.050+0200 warning: Failed to connect to      192.168.99.100:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-06-05T18:48:19.052+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.99.100:27017 (192.168.99.100), connection attempt failed at    src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

I already had a look at similar questions (e.g., [Unable to connect to mongoDB running in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828021/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker-container)) but the proposed solution does not seem to work.

Comment: Make sure that mongo container is mapped to port 27017. Try `docker ps -a` and inspect the port mapping

Comment: I did that, added the output of "docker ps" to the question.

Comment: ssh into the container and check if the mongo process is running.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was not related to Docker, but to the bindip in the configuration of MongoDB. See e.g., [mongodb.conf bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 does not work but 0.0.0.0 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588876/mongodb-conf-bind-ip-127-0-0-1-does-not-work-but-0-0-0-0-works)

Comment: This exposes the db and it should be password protected then or use an ssh tunnel