# Not able to connect SpringBootApplication to mongo container in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot

1. I'm having docker container up and running by using the following command:

   docker run -p 27017:27017 -d mongo

[Docker Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG7Oh.png) for reference.

2. Then I clone a github repo: https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-mongodb.git
3. Import the project in IntelliJ IDE, build it and run.

[SpringBoot App Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzPRN.png) here

**Issue** : I'm not able to connect to the mongo app running in the container from my `SpringBoot application` as I'm getting `MongoSocketOpenException` as shown in the logs.

> Any help is appreciated?

```
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
```

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Docker for win has some problems with loopback interfaces.

https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/

Try run docker inspect and configure your application with the container address.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan for your inputs. 
I'm just getting started with Docker.So, I'm new to this.
Could you give me an example with regards to configuration part for my application?

Comment: Can you please respond?

Comment: @ChethanB In your application you need to change the host address of mongoDB to the ip that `docker inspect` indicates to you. You should start with easier checkups to improve your debugging. Start with a simple telnet command, checking if your mongoDB is accepting connection in that port. For example `telnet localhost 27017`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
I did configure the host address of my application to the docker container IP as shown here. `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017/test`. Still, I'm facing the same issue.
I even tried telnet command to check if MongoDB is accepting connections. `telnet localhost 27017` No luck here too. 
Is this a container config problem?

Comment: So your container isn't accepting connection as localhost, try `telnet 172.17.0.2 27017`.

Comment: `Connecting To 172.17.0.2...Could not open connection to the host, on port 27017: Connect failed`
This too isn't accepting any connections.

Comment: Seems like your container isn't running

Comment: The container is running. I've made sure to check the running containers through `docker ps` command

Comment: I'm able to connect to the mongo container.
The mistake was I got the mongo container's IP instead of docker container's IP. Anyways thanks for your patience. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: I was trying to configure SpringBoot Application to mongo container IP which I retrieved from `mongo inspect <mongo_container>` command which was incorrect.

**Solution**: *Configured my application using docker IP retrieved by `docker-machine <env>` which resolved the problem.*
Link to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828021/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker-container) is here.