# Cannot connect a docker mongo container using non-standard port

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  my_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  m1:
    container_name: m1single
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 2717:27017
    volumes:
      - "./m1data:/data/db"
    networks:
      - my_net

  myclient:
    container_name: myClient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - my_net
    restart: 
      always
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

When I try to write to the mongo instance from myClient using the connection string `mongodb://m1single:2717` or `mongodb://m1:2717` (i.e. using *service* or *container* names as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828021/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker-container), not the hostname) I get:

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65d008ed8043d35059b408da, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('m1single', 2717) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('m1single:2717: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>
```

I can, however, connect to the instance through mongo compass. As soon as I set the port forwarding to `27017:27017`, however, everthing works. Is there a way around this? I'd really like to use non-standard ports for security.

Comment: Connections between containers always use the standard port numbers; they don't use `ports:` and there is no option to remap them.  How would changing the port numbers improve security?  (Having `ports:` at all is optional here, and it's a valid choice to just not publish the database outside the Docker setup.)

Comment: Using non standard ports doesn't increase security.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate this point of view, and would never rely on "security through obscurity", I disagree that "Using non standard ports doesn't increase security" - as part of a "defense in depth" approach, it can deter unsophisticated attacks that, at the very least, create additional work eg https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_MongoDB_3.4_Benchmark_Level_1_OS_Unix_v1.0.0.audit:3ba5bed2c3c752e34246b7942cf59e08 Thanks, @DavidMaze for the clarification.